# Has a new appdomain assemblies predefined?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, appdomain

Has a new appdomain assemblies predefined?  mscorlib.dll?

Comment: can you explain more? For example, do you mean: *does a new appdomain have any assemblies loaded by default?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mscorlib.dll is loaded when you use `AppDomain.CreateDomain` to create a new `AppDomain`.

If your code is running inside Visual Studio, Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities is also loaded.

An easy way to test this for yourself is by running the following code:

```
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain");
Assembly[] assemblies=ad.GetAssemblies();
foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```